# How can I get an array of element form values with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<form id="shape_layout">
    Color: <br/>
    <input type="text" name="background" id="background" value="red" /> <br/>
    <br/> Height(px): <br/>
    <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="100px" /> <br/>
    <br/> Width(px): <br/>
    <input type="text" name="width" id="width" value="100px" /> <br/>
</form>
```

That is my form, and I would like in javascript to store the "default values".

Something like:

```
document.getElementById("shape_layout").elements;
>>> this gives me [input#background, input#height, input#width]
but I would like it to give me the default values:
>>> ["red","100px","100px"]
```

Comment: So from the elements you want to map out an array of their values?

Answer (score 3):

```
let elems = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[value]")
           , el => el.value);
```

Comment: IE doesn't support `Array.from` at all

Comment: Note: Array.from has a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) for older/stupider browsers, and you can of course replace the `el => el.value` with ES5 `function(el) { return el.value; }` for wider browser support

Comment: @hellatan - IE will also choke on `el => el.value` - while `Array.from` is easily polyfilled, arrow functions need to be transpiled for Internet Exploder

Comment: @hellatan Have not tried ie in some time. You can substitute `Array.prototype.map` for `Array.from()` `Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[type=text]"), function(el) {return el.value})` https://jsfiddle.net/Lcte62fu/

Comment: @guest271314 - any reason you don't use `document.getElementById("shape_layout").elements` as the first argument for `Array.from` ?

Comment: @JaromandaX Specificity of descendant selector to meet requirement; could adjust further for greater specificity.

Comment: I get it @guest271314 :p

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are good but lacked an explanation of *what* was happening which I disliked.

Your current code is `document.getElementById("shape_layout").elements;` which is an array-like-object. Let's first write a function that takes an item as an argument and returns the new item that should replace the old one.

```
function(oldItem){
  return oldItem.value;
}
```

this can be rewritten using arrow notation as
`oldItem => oldItem.value`.

As [guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801559/guest271314) mentioned we can create a new array that also applies a function to every element, like so

`Array.from(listLikeObject, function_to_use);`

Let's plug our data in,

`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[value]"), el => el.value)`.

Trouble is, this isn't compatible with Internet Explorer because

- Arrow functions aren't supported
- `Array.from` is not supported

A basic `for` loop would probably be most compatible here. It is the approach taken in [Ionut](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3275665/ionut)'s answer.

```
var theArray = []
for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[value]").length; i++){
  theArray.push(document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[value]")[i]);
}
```

I'm now going to break this down line-by-line.

`theArray` is an array that will store the output. `var theArray = [];` sets it up as an empty array.

`for(var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[value]").length; i++)` this can be broken into three parts.

- `var i = 0;` sets `i` to `0` at the very start.
- `i < document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[value]").length` is the condition that must be satisfied every iteration of the loop. This condition makes sure that there is a list item with the index `i`, and if there is not then it will exit out of the loop.
- `i++` is a shorthand for `i = i + 1` and makes `i` 1 bigger than it was before. This happens at the end of each iteration of the loop, just before the condition is checked.

`thisArray.push` will append to the end of the array.

`document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[value]")[i]` is index notation to take the `i`th item in the array.

Comment: Oh sorry, that was a mistake.

Comment: @guest271314 ok fixed

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful! I just had one question though,

"#shape_layout input[value]"

so I know document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout") selects the form with the id = shape_layout, but what exactly does input[value] do?

Comment: `input[value]` selects all `input`s which have a `value` attribute. You should probably replace it with `input[type=text]` which matches `input` that have a `type` attribute set to `text`. `#shape_layout input[value]` matches all `input[value]`s that are within `#shape_layout` elements. This is done in case you have other types of inputs within the form (like buttons)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple `for` loop and `push()`:

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("#shape_layout input[type=text]");
  var arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (typeof elements[i].value !== "undefined") {
        arr.push(elements[i].value);
      }
    }

  console.log(arr);
```

```html
<form id="shape_layout">
    Color: <br/>
    <input type="text" name="background" id="background" value="red" /> <br/>
    <br/> Height(px): <br/>
    <input type="text" name="height" id="height" value="100px" /> <br/>
    <br/> Width(px): <br/>
    <input type="text" name="width" id="width" value="100px" /> <br/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward approach:

```
arr=[];

form=document.getElementById('shape_layout');
inputs=form.querySelectorAll('input');
for(i=0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
arr.push(inputs[i].value);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Waiting for some extra one-liner. :)

Sexier™, nice example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
inputs=document.querySelectorAll('#shape_layout input[type=text]');
vals=Array.prototype.map.call(inputs , function(el){
return el.value;
})
console.log(vals);
```